# wp_cache_set function is not working with the latest object-cache.php

Tags: wordpress, object, caching

I am using the latest version of WordPress and the latest version of `object-cache.php` (which resides in the `/wp-content` folder).

Our web server is Nginx 1.10.1.

```php
<?php

$cache_file_name= 'horo_key';
$astrowidgetcontent = wp_cache_get( $cache_file_name );
if ( !empty( $astrowidgetcontent ) ) {
    echo "<div style='display:none;'>root caching hain</div>";
    echo $astrowidgetcontent;                       
} else {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'horoscope' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12";
    $loop_horo = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql), OBJECT );
    $d                  = 1;
    $activeblock        = 'none';
    $astrowidgetcontent = '';
    $astro_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $val->ID ), array( 90, 90 ) );
    if ( !empty( $astro_image_url ) ) {
        $astrowidgetcontent .= '<img src="'.esc_url( ie_replace_imagesrc( $astro_image_url[0] ) ). '?w=90" title="' .esc_html( $val->post_title ). '" >';
    }
    wp_cache_set( $cache_file_name, $astrowidgetcontent, '', 300 );// 5 min caching 
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm not at all sure that *[showcase](http://www.onelook.com/?w=showcase&ls=a)* is the word you're looking for. Perhaps *use* would be better?

Comment: Qs is why I am not seeing the cached result